# For step, (batch_x, batch_y) in enumerate(train_data.take(training_steps), 1) error syntax

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

i am learning logistic regression from this website
[click here](https://builtin.com/data-science/guide-logistic-regression-tensorflow-20)

Step 9 does not work, the error is
[image]

what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reproduce the same error with:

```
For i in range(0,1):
    pass
```

Try changing the "For" to "for"

It looks like they just made a syntax error and you copied it.